# PIVOT and sum two columns

Tags: pivot

i hope that i Formulated the ddl +dml query and my Question without mistakes.

i build this query

```
DECLARE @temp TEHOODOTRECHESH
(
      VendorCode INT
    , VendorName NVARCHAR(50)
    , CheckDate DATETIME
    , CheckSum DECIMAL(10,2)
    , ObjType INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp TEHOODOTRECHESH (VendorCode, VendorName, CheckDate, CheckSum,ObjType
VALUES 
    (1, 'AAA', '20130101', 40,18),
    (1, 'AAA', '20130101', 60,18),
    (1, 'AAA', '20130101', 40,19),
    (2, 'BBB', '20130303', 50,18),
    (2, 'BBB', '20130601', 10,18),
    (2, 'BBB', '20130604', 20,19)


SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT 
case when [ObjType]='18' then N'tr' else N'tz' end as 'DT',  
CARDCODE, 
CardName,
year(DocDueDate) as 'year',left(datename(month,DocDueDate),3) as [month], 
DocTotal as 'Amount'
FROM TEHOODORRECHESH
WHERE DocStatus ='O' ) as monthsum
PIVOT 
(
sum (Amount)
for [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, 
nov, dec) ) AS SUMPIVOT
```

---

1. i want to sum the rows of documets from ObjType 18 / 19 (only two types)  and sum the objtype by months.
2. is there an oportunity that if the ObjType 19 to put the numbers minus opertaor (-)
   or it will in Brackets ()
3. when i wrote order by only vendor code it works, but if i add order by: vendorcode + objtype
   its not working. why?